# boto3 code to get info on ec2 -but need to know volume encryption state

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have a bit of an issue, I have this code that I created months ago and I am trying to modify it to get more info, this is where I am stuck.

I am calling describe_instances and iterating through getting the info I need. But I need to get the encryption details also of each ec2 instance volume . I believe that is under "describe_volumes"

How would I add this so my prints seem seemless, is it possible?

```
response = client.describe_instances(Filters=[{'Name':'tag-key','Values':['Name']}]) 
    ec2tags = client.describe_tags()
   # pprint(response)
    for item in response['Reservations']:
    #pprint(item['Instances'])
        pprint("AWS Account ID: {}".format(item['OwnerId']))
        for instance_id in item['Instances']:
            #print(instance_id)
            Tags = instance_id['Tags']
            tag_name_value = ""
            for tag in Tags:
                if tag['Key'] == "Name":
                    tag_name_value = tag["Value"]
                    break
            #Tags = instance_id['Tags']['Value']
            State = instance_id['State']['Name']
            #print("EC2 Name: {}".format(Tags))
            print("EC2 Name: {}".format(tag_name_value))
            print("Instance Id is: {}\nInstance Type is: {}".format(instance_id['InstanceId'],instance_id['InstanceType']))
            print("EC2 State is: {}".format(State))
            if 'VpcId' in instance_id:
                print("VPC Id is: {}".format(instance_id['VpcId']))
for volumes in instance_id['BlockDeviceMappings']:
                vol_list = [ vol['Ebs']['VolumeId'] for vol in instance_id['BlockDeviceMappings']]
```

when I run it, I get this:

```
'AWS Account ID: 123456789012'
EC2 Name: ec2_web
Instance Id is: i-0d3c64d8771ru57574
Instance Type is: t2.small
EC2 State is: stopped
VPC Id is: vpc-026efa5966396
```

I want it to look like this

```
'AWS Account ID: 123456789012'
EC2 Name: ec2_web
Instance Id is: i-0d3c64d8771ru57574
Instance Type is: t2.small
EC2 State is: stopped
VPC Id is: vpc-026efa5966396
Volume Id:  ['vol-054f5ef5eeb2025b0']
Volume Encrypt: true or false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [describe_volumes](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_volumes).

```
response = client.describe_instances(Filters=[{'Name':'tag-key','Values':['Name']}]) 
ec2tags = client.describe_tags()
# pprint(response)
for item in response['Reservations']:
#pprint(item['Instances'])
    pprint("AWS Account ID: {}".format(item['OwnerId']))
    for instance_id in item['Instances']:
        #print(instance_id)
        Tags = instance_id['Tags']
        tag_name_value = ""
        for tag in Tags:
            if tag['Key'] == "Name":
                tag_name_value = tag["Value"]
                break
        #Tags = instance_id['Tags']['Value']
        State = instance_id['State']['Name']
        #print("EC2 Name: {}".format(Tags))
        print("EC2 Name: {}".format(tag_name_value))
        print("Instance Id is: {}\nInstance Type is: {}".format(instance_id['InstanceId'],instance_id['InstanceType']))
        print("EC2 State is: {}".format(State))
        if 'VpcId' in instance_id:
            print("VPC Id is: {}".format(instance_id['VpcId']))

    for volumes in instance_id['BlockDeviceMappings']:
        vol_list = [vol['Ebs']['VolumeId'] for vol in instance_id['BlockDeviceMappings']]

    volume_infos = client.describe_volumes(VolumeIds=vol_list)

    for vol in volume_infos['Volumes']:
        print(f"Volume Id:  {vol['VolumeId']}")
        print(f"Volume Encrypt: {vol['Encrypted']}")
```

Note that there are some indentation issues in your code. Thus you have to fix them as well.

Comment: thank you.. works perfect. The indention seem to get all messed up when I did the copy/paste..